# Setting domains in resolvectl results in timeouts

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

For some reason I can't manage to set domains for resolvectl. Either I don't understand what it does at all or something is weird for me.

Once I set a domain e.g. `sudo resolvectl domain enp2s0 example.com`, any query to `example.com` or any of its subdomains result in timeouts and NXDOMAIN for searched queries.

Why am I experiencing that? Also doesn't this feature actually work simply just like `search` in `resolv.conf` file but namespaced by network interface? i.e. If I query `subdomain` which is acutally nothing but `subdomain.example.com` and it has answers on that interface DNS servers I should resolve it successfully, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, it had nothing to do with resolvectl, I just had `DNSOverTLS=yes` enforced in my `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` while the DNS server didn't support DNS over TLS